# google map auto update location but not user set zoom

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

I am auto updating google maps every x seconds in jquery/javascript.

When location is changed map changes the zoom level (expected).

But i want to achieve this:

If user has manually changed zoom level, then the map should keep/persist the user-set zoom level.

Code looks similar to this:

```
  function calcRoute(user) {
     if(user)
     {
        start = document.getElementById("start_location").value;
     }
     end = document.getElementById("end_location").value;
     var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        $('#txt_dur').text(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
        $('#txt_dist').text(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);      

      }
    });
    //if(userZoom==true)
    //    map.setZoom(current_zoom);

  }

      function autoUpdate() {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
         var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                          position.coords.longitude);

         start = newPoint.toString();
         calcRoute(false);
      });

    setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);
   }

    autoUpdate();
```

I will prefer standard google map events
like zoom_changed instead of creating custom events for user zoom.

Any directions on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var tmpZoom = map.getZoom();   //added line
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    map.setZoom( tmpZoom );        //added line

    $('#txt_dur').text(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
    $('#txt_dist').text(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
}
```

where `map` is your `google.maps.Map` object.

**P.S.**: For preventing both `center` and `zoom` from being changed by `setDirections` method, you can specify `preserveViewport=true` of [google.maps.DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) object.

Comment: preserveViewport=true wont help. because i want center of the map to change

Comment: @mashit Yeah, I doubted about it, that's why I put that sentence on *PS* section.

Comment: yeah. is there a way to differentiate whether zoom was changed by user or it was changed because of map auto update?

Comment: @mashit No. You need to handle the all such interactions made by user.

Comment: for auto updating/refreshing the map, i am changing start location to current location every x seconds. is there a better approach for this?

Comment: and how to handle such interactions. any directions you can provide?

Comment: @mashit About interactions, it'll not be so easy. You need to listen all `mousedown` and `mousewheel` events on map's div. Then check mouse's x and y positions relative to zoom's controlbar. Also `zoom_change`,`dblclick` events on `google.maps.Map` object,to perform some checkings. I think, it's hard task.

Comment: yes. i thought so. cant this be achieved using zoom_changed event of map per se?

Comment: I don't think ,it will cover all the cases. Maybe some tricks by `setTimeout`,`setInterval` can do something, but it would be too far from completeness.

Comment: @mashit You may ask in StackOverlow such a question. Maybe there could be other thoughts than mine.